# Cakephp Bake - table not found in datasource

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, controller, cakephp-2.0

### Issue

I'm trying to get Cakephp to bake a controller, and I'm given an error:

```
Error: Table core_tablets for model CoreTablet was not found in datasource dev.
```

### Background Information

- I'm using Lappstack for my Apache, PHP, and Postgresql
- Postgresql 9.0.3 database
- PHP 5.3
- Apache 2
- Cakephp 2.3.1

### What I am able to do

- I am able to bake a model. I've created a model for each of the controllers so far.
- The webapp works fine. I've built Models, Controllers, and Views from scratch and everything works.
- Connect to DB from web app, remotely using pgadmin3, and psql

### Full Cakephp Bake error

```
Enter a number from the list above,
type in the name of another controller, or 'q' to exit
[q] > CoreTablets
---------------------------------------------------------------
Baking CoreTabletsController
---------------------------------------------------------------
Would you like to build your controller interactively? (y/n)
[y] > n
Would you like to create some basic class methods
(index(), add(), view(), edit())? (y/n)
[n] > y
Would you like to create the basic class methods for admin routing? (y/n)
[n] >
Error: Table core_tablets for model CoreTablet was not found in datasource dev.
#0 /home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/apache2/htdocs/cpm_v2_dev/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3231): Model->setSource('core_tablets')
#1 /home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/apache2/htdocs/cpm_v2_dev/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1319): Model->getDataSource()
#2 /home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/apache2/htdocs/cpm_v2_dev/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1402): Model->schema()
#3 /home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/apache2/htdocs/cpm_v2_dev/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1390): Model->hasField('title', false)
#4 /home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/apache2/htdocs/cpm_v2_dev/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(879): Model->hasField(Array)
#5 /home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/apache2/htdocs/cpm_v2_dev/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ControllerTask.php(301): Model->__get('displayField')
#6 /home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/apache2/htdocs/cpm_v2_dev/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ControllerTask.php(189): ControllerTask->bakeActions('CoreTablets', NULL, true)
#7 /home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/apache2/htdocs/cpm_v2_dev/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ControllerTask.php(62): ControllerTask->_interactive()
#8 /home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/apache2/htdocs/cpm_v2_dev/lib/Cake/Console/Command/BakeShell.php(114): ControllerTask->execute()
#9 /home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/apache2/htdocs/cpm_v2_dev/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(392): BakeShell->main()
#10 /home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/apache2/htdocs/cpm_v2_dev/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(200): Shell->runCommand(NULL, Array)
#11 /home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/apache2/htdocs/cpm_v2_dev/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(68): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#12 /home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/apache2/htdocs/cpm_v2_dev/app/Console/cake.php(37): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#13 {main}
```

### Config file: app/config/database.php

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '5433',
    'login' => 'notrealusername',
    'password' => 'notrealpassword',
    'database' => 'notrealdatabase',
    'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'notrealschema',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

public $dev = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '5433',
    'login' => 'notrealusername',
    'password' => 'notrealpassword',
    'database' => 'notrealdatabase',
        'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'notrealschema',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

The host used to be the external IP address, which worked fine but I changed it to 127.0.0.1 since other articles have mentioned bake plays nicer with 127.0.0.1.

### Research

I've found two related Stackoverflow articles, but they don't seem to solve my issue.

Changing the IP address didn't seem to help.
[cake console 2.2.1: Bake errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785486/cake-console-2-2-1-bake-errors?rq=1)

This is using a sqlite database which is an actual file. I'm using postgresql and this won't work.
[Bake tool cannot see tables in SQLite3 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370765/bake-tool-cannot-see-tables-in-sqlite3-database)

Comment: Did you create the table "core_tablets" in the database first before baking?

Comment: Yes, every table was created in the database before baking. I was getting an error when baking the models. It was saying that the table could not be found.

Comment: Is it spelled correctly? What models do you see when you do *cake bake* then choose *model* by typing *M* from the selection list.

Comment: @Kelvin Yes, the table is spelled correctly. When I do *./cake bake* and choose *M* I receiving a listing of all Models currently in /app/Model

Comment: Is dev datasource and default datasource the same database? Could it be possible the table may be present in the default DB and not the dev DB?

Comment: @Kelvin Yes, both datasources are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue ending up being with permissions on the table. `./cake bake` can't see the database if the user defined in `app/config/database.php` does not have permissions on the tables. All I needed to do was add permissions on the tables. This is what I did in my Postgresql database:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE my_schema.my_table TO notrealusername
```

I also add permission to the sequences used by the tables:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE my_schema.my_table TO notrealusername
```

The `SQL` is for `Postgresql 9.1`

Adding the permission to the sequences didn't make a difference for using the Bake utility, but it would have caused problems down the road when trying to insert new records that depend on a sequence for a default value.